# jQuery/JS: Get current URL parent directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

From:

> http://www.site.com/example/index.html

How can I get just:

> http://www.site.com/example/

And storing it into a variable using Javascript and how using jQuery also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minor nitpick... That's not a "directory".  It's part of the URL of a resource.  It may *map* to a directory on the server, but a URL itself does not have a directory because HTTP is not a file system.

Comment: Thanks for the info, appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var myURL = "http://www.site.com/example/index.html";
var myDir = myURL.substring( 0, myURL.lastIndexOf( "/" ) + 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(location).prop("href").split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/")
```

---

**Demo process with the current page:**

1. $(location)

   ```
   {
       "ancestorOrigins": {
       },
       "hash": "",
       "host": "stackoverflow.com",
       "hostname": "stackoverflow.com",
       "href": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497045/jquery-js-get-current-url-parent-directory",
       "origin": "https://stackoverflow.com",
       "pathname": "/questions/17497045/jquery-js-get-current-url-parent-directory",
       "port": "",
       "protocol": "https:",
       "search": ""
   }
   ```
2. $(location).prop("href")

   ```
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497045/jquery-js-get-current-url-parent-directory
   ```
3. $(location).prop("href").split("/")

   ```
   [
       "https:",
       "",
       "stackoverflow.com",
       "questions",
       "17497045",
       "jquery-js-get-current-url-parent-directory"
   ]
   ```
4. $(location).prop("href").split("/").slice(0,-1)

   ```
   [
       "https:",
       "",
       "stackoverflow.com",
       "questions",
       "17497045"
   ]
   ```

   *※ The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument. Use negative numbers to select from the end of an array.*
5. $(location).prop("href").split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/")

   ```
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497045
   ```

---

**Notes and References:**

- [location](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/obj_location.asp): The location object contains information about the current URL.
- [href](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_loc_href.asp): The entire URL of the current page.
- [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName): Get the value of a property for the element.
- [.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp): The method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.
- [.slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp): The method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.
- [.join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp): The method joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.

Comment: Would you mind extending your answer, for fellow programmers, in order to understand, how exactly it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: This is a much better answer as you can easily get the grandparent, etc.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/mXpBx/

```
var s1 = "http://www.site.com/example/index.html";
var s2 = s1.replace(s1.split("/").pop(),"");
```

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work

```js
new URL(".", "http://example.com/folder/subfolder/file.js")
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HM4ss/)**

```
var a = "http://www.site.com/example/index.html";
var b = a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf('/'))+"/";
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex would do the same, but in this example a regex is not the most simple solution.

```
var url = "http://www.site.com/example/index.html";
var newUrl = url.match(/^(.*[\\\/])/)[1];
```