# Get parent page URL from a child page

Tags: javascript

I have the javascript code below to put my parent menu item to class active when I'm on the page for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ it works. But I also wanna put the parent menu item to class active when I'm at the subpages/child menu item like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/, may I know how to do that?

Example I'm at this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, how to I get the URL like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions, without the /ask so that I can have the parent menu item (question) to be in active class when I'm at the child page of question which is (ask).

```
    <script>
      var url = window.parent.location.href;
      $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

      $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
      }).parent().addClass('active');
    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JS: Get current URL parent directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497045/jquery-js-get-current-url-parent-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try String.split()

```
url = window.parent.location.href;
parts = url.split('/');
parent = parts[parts.length-2]; // or -3 if your URL has a trailing slash
```